# Inheriting CCSprite in Cocos2d-iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, inheritance, cocos2d-iphone

I've ready many places that tell me I shouldn't inherit the CCSprite class and rather just add a sprite to my class as a member variable.

Here is what I've done:
Created a CCNode class,
Added a CCSprite variable to my node class,
Initialized my sprite and added it as a child to my node.

I now have a CCLayer where I want to draw these sprites but when I add my node as a child nothing is drawn. If I add the nodes sprite as the child rather than the node it will draw.

My question is, is there anyway to get my sprites to draw from adding the node as a child to the layer or is adding the sprites the only way?

I'm new to Objective-c and iPhone dev so any help will be greatly appreciated.

*Edit*
Here is my CCNode Class - animalSprite is my CCSprite.

```
    @implementation Animal

    @synthesize animalSprite = _animalSprite;

    -(Animal *) initWithFile:(NSString *)texture position:(CGPoint) position
    {
        self.animalSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:texture];
        self.animalSprite.position = position;
        self.animalSprite.scale = 0.25f;
        [self addChild:self.animalSprite];

        return self;
    }

    -(void) dealloc{

        [super dealloc];
    }

@end
```

Now in my CCLayer class I have a level variable that contains a list of my nodes.

```
//Load Level
Level *level = [LoadLevel loadLevel];

for (Animal *animal in level.animals)
{
    [self addChild:animal];
}
```

*Edit I create my node objects and then add them to the array in the levels class the following way.*

```
Animal *animal = [[[Animal alloc] initWithFile:animalFileName position:position] autorelease];
[level.animals addObject:animal];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reading this thread http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11566

Hopefully you have the same issue where the sprite is being released before you use it.

Cheers,

Taz

Latest game Chained: http://www.silverbacktechsol.co.uk/stschained.html

Comment: Ok this article suggests instead of inheriting from a CCNode, I inherit from an NSObject and then just add the sprite to the layer. I guess this makes sense but if I wanted to retrieve the child from the layer I'd only get the sprite and not the NSObject right?

Comment: Also I can't see anywhere in my code where my parent class might be releasing it's children, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Do you not need to add the following around your sprite initialisation block?

`if ((self=[super init]) ) {`
`}`

Try that, see if it solves the problem.

In my experience if you subclass objects you need to call the parents initialisation before anything else.  PS I'm away from my Mac so can't try this out myself, I'm just remembering from memory ;-)

Comment: Ah, I knew it would be something simple that I've missed. Thanks a lot :)